# JSON.stringify doesn't run replacer function on certain object properties

Tags: javascript, json

I have this specific JavaScript object:

```js
var a = {x: Infinity, y: NaN, z: 'hello'};
```

When I run `JSON.stringify(a, r)` on that object using a certain replacer function (below) in the following code, I get the expected `console.log`s:

Code:

```js
var a = {
  x: Infinity,
  y: NaN,
  z: 'hello'
};

var r = function(key, value) {
  console.log(value);

  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return undefined;
  }

  return value;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(a, r));
```

Output:

```js
{x: Infinity, y: NaN, z: "hello"}
Infinity
NaN
hello
{"x":null,"y":null}
```

However, when I make this small modification to the replacer function, `JSON.stringify(a, r)` doesn't seem to iterate over any of the object's properties and returns `[object Object]`:

```js
var a = {
  x: Infinity,
  y: NaN,
  z: 'hello'
};

var r = function(key, value) {
  console.log(value);

  if (!isFinite(value)) {
    return value.toString();
  }

  return value;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(a, r));
```

Output:

```js
{x: Infinity, y: NaN, z: "hello"}
"[object Object]"
```

I'm trying to get the function to return

```js
{"x":"Infinity", "y":"NaN", "z":"hello"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter):

> Initially, the replacer function is called with an empty string as key representing the object being stringified. It is then called for each property on the object or array being stringified.

This is why you are getting `"[object Object]"` when `toString` is called on the entire object

Since the `key` is empty string for this scenario, you can just add `if(key)` to the beginning of your check

```js
const a = {
  x: Infinity,
  y: NaN,
  z: 'hello'
};

function replacer(key, value) {
  if (key && !isFinite(value)) {
    return String(value);
  }

  return value;
};

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(a, replacer, 4)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the type as well.

```js
var a = { x: Infinity, y: NaN, z: 'hello' },
    r = function(key, value) {
        if (typeof value === 'number' && !isFinite(value)) return value.toString();
        return value;
    };

console.log(JSON.stringify(a, r));
```